# Where can I find Calvin's commentary on the Hebrew Bible in the original Latin?

Tags: resource-request, calvin

Where can I find Calvin's commentary on the Hebrew Bible in the original Latin? I am looking to find his comments on Genesis 12.

Answer (score 4):

The [Post-Reformation Digital Library](http://www.prdl.org/) is the best place I've found for these sorts of documents.  And, sure enough, a [search for "Calvin" and "Genesis"](http://www.prdl.org/adv_search.php?q1=&q1cat=any&q2op=and&q2=genesis&q2cat=title&q3op=and&q3=calvin&q3cat=author&q4op=and&q4=&q4cat=place&q5op=and&q5=&q5cat=p_name&q6op=and&q6=&q6cat=ser_title&q7op=and&qfr=&qto=&q8op=and&qfr_add=&qto_add=&q9op=and&q_src_type=&q10op=and&q_tradition=&q11op=and&q_topic=&q12op=and&q_genre=&q13op=and&q_lang=&q14op=and&q_bib=&sort=author&s=0&limit=20&Submit=Search) includes the following results:

- [*In Primum Mosis Libru[m], qui Genesis vulgo dicitur, Commentarius Iohannis Calvini*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8ntTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA84), 1554, page 84
- [*Commentarii Ioannis Caluini in quinque libros Mosis, Genesis seorsum reliqui quatuor in formam harmoniae digesti*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ol7_ICKhNWgC&pg=PA96), 2ed, 1573, page 96

The page numbers indicate where, according to the book's internal pagination, the commentary on Genesis 12 begins.